# jquery will not work in file retrieved by java select include

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a simple form that  that when changed includes a php file in a div.  For some reason jquery will not load when placed in that included file?  Can someone tell me why this doesnt work.

```
    <select name='make' onChange='show(this.value)'>
<option value='some-file.php'>the file</option>
</select>


<div id="make">Where the file is loaded and where jquery wont work</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("make").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("make").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","include/some-file.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Then some-file.php

```
    $models = mysql_query("SELECT model, id FROM model where make like '%".$q."%' order by model asc") or die(mysql_error());
    //Puts it into an array
$count = 1;

$max = 3;

while($model = mysql_fetch_array( $models ))
{

if($count%20==1)
    echo '</ul><ul style="float:left; padding:0; margin-right:10px;" class="makesModels">';

echo "<li style='padding-right:5px; display:block;'><font color='#fe9000'>".$count.".</font> ".$model['model']."&nbsp;<a class='delete-model".$model['id']."'>x</a></li>";

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(docuument).ready(function() {
$(".delete-model<? echo $model['id'];?>").click(function() {                        
alert("delete");
                                                                });
});
</script>

$count++;
}

?>
```

Comment: give us your show funtion and correct your line 2 </option. to </option>

Comment: Does the select have only one option? or it has multiple? because with one option the onchange function never works

Comment: yes, but thats not the problem.  it loads the file fine.  in the file it loads I have some jquery... the jquery won't work in the file, but works fine if the file is not loaded that way?

Comment: You should have jquery in this page included to work correct

Comment: Please post your code in the PHP page where the problem is, this code is fine

Comment: edit tag To JavaScript .. there is no jQuery here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it, because the code is not complete, my guess would be that on someotherphpfile that you are importing you use document.ready function which is not calling because you load the file using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

i've had the same exact problem ...

to solve this all you need to do is edit the ajax from using normal JavaScript to `$.ajax` so use jQuery to handle it .. and it will work ..

```
$.ajax({
  url: "include/some-file.php?q="+str,
  type: "GET",
  datatype: 'html',
  success: function(e){
    $('#make').html(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: added some code for more details please see the jquery documentation

Comment: again further edit .. i have converted the javascript ajax request to jquery .. you can use it

Answer (score 0):

scripts loaded with ajax or in general a script string injected in the DOM will not execute for security reasons

you can use eval to get it working although i must warn you that you could be opening a can of worms..

after `document.getElementById("make").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` add this..

```
var parent = document.getElementById('make');
var myScript = parent.getElementsByTagName('script');
for(var i=0,len=myScript.length; i<len; i++){
   executeScrpt(myScript[i]);
 }
```

then the execute function...

```
 function executeScrpt(scrpt){
    if(scrpt.innerHTML != ""){
         eval("("+script.innerHTML+")");
    } else {
        if(scrpt.src != ""){
            var myScrpt = document.createElement("script");
            myScrpt.src = scrpt.src;
            document.head.appendChild(myScrpt);
        }
    }
 }
```