# Ajax call to file with <script> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a sample page that works to replicate table layout pages without using the very mobile-unfriendly table features.

Basically I have a page that looks like so:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
    <div type="page">
        <div class="header">
        </div> <!-- /header -->
        <div class="body">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                $(".header").load("/common/header.html");
                                $(".body").load("/Example/example-home.html");
                                //Call to superclass function to replace contents after load
                    });
                /*$(document).ready(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Example/example-home.html",
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        $(".body").append(data);
                    });
                });*/
            </script> -->
            </div> <!-- /body -->
        </div class="footer">
        </div> <!-- /footer -->
    </div> <!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

The file that is being called via ajax looks like:

```
    <style>
    /* Various CSS Stylings */
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*Populate our scripts upon ajax request
        var sList[0] = ["Color Mutate", "Versatile, Schemebale, string mutation script. Format your text in any color scheme you can dream.", "1.2.0"];
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (!sList) {
                $(".table").html("<p>No hosted scripts found</p>");
            } else {
                for (var i = 0;i<=sList.length;i++) {
                    $(".script").append(sList[i][0]);
                    $(".desc").append(sList[i][1]);
                    $(".version").append(sList[i][2]);
                }
            }
        }); */ 
                    // moved to main.js
    </script>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="script">
        </div>

        <div class="desc">
        </div>

        <div class="version">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /table -->
```

And the ajax call is successful when viewed in firebug, the resulting output looks identical to the example-home.html file, but the browser shows nothing in the `<div class="body"></div>` section afterwards.

I fear it's an issue with the asynchronous nature of ajax calls, but cannot seem to figure out a viable solution.

**EDIT** I have also tried doing `$(this).append()` instead of the `$(".body").append()` as shown above to no avail as well.

**EDIT 2** Updated to working code

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148037/jquery-will-not-work-in-file-retrieved-by-java-select-include/15148567#15148567

Comment: Why do you have the javascript in div.body and not at the end of your page?

Comment: @Josh Sigh, guess I won't be able to make it as modular as i would have liked. I guess I'll put it into my base class and execute it after load

Comment: @popnoodles Just makes it easier to find later on when I'm adding new interfaces.

Comment: Try `$(".body").load("/Example/example-home.html");`

Comment: important to realize that `document.ready` has already occurred in main page, so new code will fire immediately and thus before the html exists. Swap order so script is after html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of errors in your second page:  `$(document).ready({...});` needs to be  `$(document).ready(function(){...});` 
and `var sList[0] = [...];` should be `sList[0] = [...];`, and there should also be a `var sList=[];` declaration, probably made in the first page.

Then, in the first page, add `dataType: 'text'` and you might find it works fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Example/example-home.html",
        dataType: 'text'
    }).done(function (data) {
        $(".body").append(data);
    });
});
```

Oh and drop the `<html>` tag from the pages you're loading in asynchronously.

Comment: Nods, I just fixed the errors as I was searching for it. Now using a combination of .load() and superclass level mod functions was able to get it to work. I have accepted your answer as it fairly close to my final solution. Thanks for the help.